# rendered property not changing the style

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

i try to hide/show a form but it not working for me.

```
 <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!stockError}">
        <apex:form>
             <apex:pageBlock title="Stock Error">
                 <apex:pageMessages id="StockErrorMessage"></apex:pageMessages>
                <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                   <apex:commandButton action="{!continueOrder}" value="Continue Order" reRender="false"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
             </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
 </apex:outputPanel>
```

Controller

```
public class shopController {

    public  List <Product__c> productList {get;set;}
    public  List <Product__c> queryList {get;set;}
    public String prodId {get;set;}
    private String message;
    private Integer numOfItemsInCart;
    // list contains the product code of each item in the cart 
    private List<String> cart;
    public Boolean stockError {get;set;}

    public shopController(){
        productList = [Select Id, Name, product_code__c,price__c,stock__c From Product__c];
        prodId ='';
        message = '';
        numOfItemsInCart = 0;
        cart =  new List<String>();
        stockError = false;
    }

    public void addToCart(){
        ++numOfItemsInCart;
        cart.add(prodId);
        message = 'Item added to cart, number of items in your cart is: '+ numOfItemsInCart;
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,message));
    }
    public void completeOrder(){
        stockError = true;
        queryList =  [Select Id From Product__c where product_code__c IN:cart AND stock__c > 0 ];
        //if the size of the cart not equal to the size of the querylist that means that at list 1 item is not in stock
        //and the user should get message
        if(queryList.size() != cart.size()){
            System.debug('error');
        }
        else{
            //continue to confirmation page
            System.debug(queryList);
        }
    }
    public void continueOrder(){

    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here? On clicking commandbutton,continueorder function is called,but it is not setting the stockError variable.Also why are you setting rerender to "false"? rerender should be some id of the component that you try to refresh after an action.On what condition should the output panel refresh?

Comment: `Rendered` is only used for hide and show, not for styling!

Comment: i have on other section abutton that have some logic. after i click on that button i want to hide/ show the panel i put here.

Comment: you want to change the styling according to a value of `stockError` variable ?

Comment: yes.. i just want to show the panel when the stockError is true and hide when it false

Comment: there is not enough information here; please use [edit] to expose the part of the controller that sets `stockError` to true and any VF components that rerender the portion of the page where your outputPanel sits within

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, the method `completeOrder()` is the one who put the variable `stockError` to `true`, so if you have another button that calls this method you should add `reRender` attribute to it.

it might be something like this :

```
 <apex:page...>
    <style type="text/css">
    .GeneralStatusBlack{
        position:fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
        z-index: 100;
    }
    .GeneralStatus{
        position:fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-left: -52px;
        margin-top: -26px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 2px solid;
        z-index: 8;
    }
    .GeneralStatusGif{
        position:fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        margin-left: -16px;
        margin-top: -16px;
        background-image:url('/img/loading32.gif');
        z-index: 9;
    }
   </style>
    ...
    <apex:commandLink value="Compelete Order" action="{!completeOrder}" reRender="myPanel" status="GeneralStatus" styleClass="btn"/>


     <apex:outputPanel id="myPanel" rendered="{!stockError}">
        <apex:form>
             <apex:pageBlock title="Stock Error">
                 ...           
             </apex:pageBlock>
            ...

        <apex:actionStatus id="GeneralStatus" onstop="jsHelpers()">
            <apex:facet name="start">
                <apex:outputPanel >
                    <div class="GeneralStatusBlack">
                        <div class="GeneralStatus">
                            <div class="GeneralStatusGif">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:facet name="stop">
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>
   </apex:page>
```

Note that the `apex:commandLink` tag can also be `apex:commandButton` tag

and then the `completeOrder` action should return `PageReference` type with null value:

```
    public PageReference completeOrder(){
       stockError = true;
       queryList =  [Select Id From Product__c where product_code__c IN:cart AND stock__c > 0 ];
       //if the size of the cart not equal to the size of the querylist that means that at list 1 item is not in stock
    //and the user should get message
       if(queryList.size() != cart.size()){
           System.debug('error');
       }
       else{
           //continue to confirmation page
        System.debug(queryList);
       }

       return null;
   }
```

I hope this solve your problem.